# best practice for sensitive configuration data in source control?

Tags: version-control, deployment, production-environment

I've seen a few approaches to this problem so I'm curious what the SO community has to say about it.

If I have configuration data that is used for accessing a production database (specifically a connection string):

- Is it a bad idea to keep that information in source control (e.g. another avenue of attack for hackers)?
- If you aren't keeping it in source control then where would you keep it?
- Is this a case of "if they've gotten in to your source control server you're pretty screwed anyway"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you're worried about that issue (a concern which, frankly, I don't share), you can save your connection string encoded, with the key stored somewhere else (= a different server).

Comment: I'm not convinced that I should be concerned about it either. What's your reasoning for not worrying about it?

Comment: firstly- hopefully, if you're working in a company, your source control isn't on a public server. so that's a little safer. secondly- your production db might not be of great value- if you develop banking / e-commerce application or apps that hold other sensitive data then yes, but otherwise- who would bother? thirdly, and most importantly- it's probably easier to hack *your* application than it is to hack your source control (I know it's true for my apps :) )

Comment: "Who would bother" has never been legitimate risk-mitigation, and that's become very apparent as time goes on. People reuse passwords all over the place. A breach of one site can have substantial cascading consequences.

Comment: That said, if your VCS is hosted on a well-protected server, and implements its own access control beyond that, and you disallow checkout/clone to non-company systems, you might be ok.

Comment: @Novelocrat: I half-agree on your first point. 'who would bother' isn't an argument on its own, and shouldn't be viewed as a license to leave yourself unprotected. it's just a consideration as to the lengths you'd go to protect yourself. In context of this question: the fact that you're not holding anything of value *may* be a consideration as to the level of non-trivial security (such as- securing the db password in source control) you'd want to have